# How do I format date and time in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Not able to format the entire column, (want to format, remove `-` , `:`)

```sh
+---------------------+---------------------+
|  pickup_datetime    |  dropoff_datetime   |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2016-02-29 16:40:21 | 2016-02-29 16:47:01 |
| 2016-03-11 23:35:37 | 2016-03-11 23:53:57 |
| 2016-02-21 17:59:33 | 2016-02-21 18:26:48 |
| 2016-01-05 09:44:31 | 2016-01-05 10:03:32 |
| 2016-02-17 06:42:23 | 2016-02-17 06:56:31 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

```py
var1 = data["pickup_datetime"][0]
data_object = datetime.strptime(var1,"%y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s")
data

var1 = data["pickup_datetime"][0]
data_object = datetime.strptime(var1,"%y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s")
data
```

```sh
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-80-80ffac5f9c8d> in <module>

      1 import datetime
----> 2 var1 = data["pickup_datetime"][0]
      3 data_object = datetime.strptime(var1,"%y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s")
      4 data

TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Format your code, it will help others understand your question easier

Comment: What is the format your want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `import datetime`, it should be `from datetime import datetime` and the datetime format should be `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`.

E.g.:

```
In [10]: datetime.strptime('2016-02-29 16:40:21', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
Out[10]: datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 29, 16, 40, 21)
```

More details you can find https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior